# I can't find the exact limits to find the marginal probability density function (PDF) from a uniformly joint PDF.

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

For a uniform probability density function (PDF) of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, the PDF exists only in the square of length $\sqrt{2}$, whose vertices are $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$ (please see attached image below, where I also defined the equations of the lines).

Now, we know that the area of this square is $2$, and its PDF is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Now, if I want to find the marginal PDF of $X$, for example, I want to sum the joint PDF over all values $Y$ can take. But I don't know what the limits of integration will be. Do I just sum from -1 to 1 for $y$?

[image: The uniform PDF exists only within this square; the equations for the line segments are also given]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are finding the marginal pdf of $X$ from the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$, you are calculating the integral
$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, \mathrm dy\tag{1}$$
in which *$x$ is just a constant*, say $0.123$ or $-0.456$. That is, you need to evaluate $(1)$ for uncountably infinitely many values of $x$. However, things are not as bad as this suggests, because we can figure out the value of $f(x)$ for huge chunks of values of $x$ if we just try to draw a few more lines on the figure that you have sketched.  For example, Eq. $(1)$ tells us that
*for any choice of* $x \in [-1,0)$,
\begin{align}f_X(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, \mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{-1-x}^{1+x} \frac 12\, \mathrm dy\end{align}
*which you can figure out by drawing a vertical line at some choice of $x \in [-1,0)$ and checking where it intersects the edges of the joint pdf support*. You even have the equations for the edges marked on your sketch!!
Similarly,  *for any choice of* $x \in [0,1]$,
\begin{align}f_X(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, \mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{-1+x}^{1-x} \frac 12\, \mathrm dy.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! The vertical line seems intuitive. I can paint a picture in my mind of summing over the entire y axis (so to speak) for that particular value of x. Since the joint PDF exists only in the square, the limits to run between are on the intersection points. This helped me revise multi variable calculus too!

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this it is often handsome to go for finding the CDF of $X$.

Observe that for $x\in[-1,0]$ we have: $$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)=\frac12(1+x)^2$$

This expression corresponds with area of triangle with vertices $(-1,0)$,$(x,x)$ and $(x,-x)$ divided by $2$.

For $x\in[0,1]$ we find on a similar way that: $$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)=1-\frac12(1-x)^2$$

To be complete we note that (of course) $F_X(x)=0$ for $x<-1$ and that $F_X(x)=1$ for $x>1$.

Now PDF $f_X(x)$ can be found by differentiating $F_X(x)$ leading to:$$f_X(x)=1-|x|\text{ if }|x|\leq1\text{ and }f_X(x)=0\text{ otherwise}$$

Comment: How did we get the CDF of X when we don't know its PDF? Also, the triangle you described, wouldn't it essentially have two vertices, since (-1,1) is on the (x,-x) line?

Comment: You are correct about vertex $(-1,1)$. That should be $(-1,0)$. That was a typo and is repaired now. We definitely do not need the PDF of $X$ to find its CDF. Note that for every subset $A$ of the diamond we can find $P((X,Y)\in A)$ just by taking half of the area of $A$ (formally the Lebesgue measure of $A$). This because we are dealing with uniform distribution. That is practicized in my answer.

Comment: Fascinating. This Lebesgue is new for me. I'll look into it. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: You are very welcome.